# Meteor's find method only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

What is wrong with my code. `Meteor.users.findOne()` or `Meteor.user.find()` only works in Chrome. Does not work in Firefox nor Safari -- Im on a Mac. My error is:

> TypeError: Meteor.users.findOne(...) is undefined

I want to have a user profile so upon registration, the profile field is created using Reactjs:

**Registration component (Client)**:

```
Accounts.createUser({
 ...
 profile: [] //later you'll see why for this.
});
```

**Server:**

```
// We us this to add more fields to a user registration:
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user['regtype'] = options.regtype,
  user['profile'] = options.profile
  return user
});

Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'regtype': 1, 'profile': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

**The error comes from my Profile.jsx:**

```
...
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    };
  },
  getInitialState(){
    profile = Meteor.users.findOne().profile; // the error is here
    return{name: profile.name}
  }
...
```

Strangely if I `console.log(Meteor.user.find())` it shows as undefined. But works great in Chrome only. I have not tried MS Edge.

Comment: It should be `console.log(Meteor.users.find())` instead of `console.log(Meteor.user.find())`

Comment: Well I need to current user. Works on their github page: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/commit/9b01c38c2ec27fed6653fa5e6efa2b83bc34cd8b

Comment: That is `Meteor.user()`. There is no `Meteor.user.find()`. . Becuase `Meteor.user()` returns an object not a collection. But `Meteor.users()` returns a collection. Hence you can use `Meteor.users.findOne()`

Comment: Ok. Ive changed it. But getting `TypeError: Meteor.user(...) is undefined` and thats only in firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is happening. When user is not logged in then `Meteor.user()` returns `null`. Have you added all the default accounts packages?

Comment: Only `accounts-password ` since I want custom registration.

Comment: Check if there is `accounts-base` package in the packages file in .meteor directory

Comment: did that solve the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100126/discussion-between-tkay-and-sylar).

Comment: @tkay At first but I needed the binding so I've written this: http://goo.gl/uC8fYb

Answer (score 1):

According to meteor docs

> The basic Accounts system is in the accounts-base package, but
>   applications typically include this automatically by adding one of the
>   login provider packages: accounts-password, accounts-facebook,
>   accounts-github, accounts-google, accounts-meetup, accounts-twitter,
>   or accounts-weibo.

So If you have the `accounts-base` package you'll get the `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.users()` functions. Check your .meteor/packages file for `account-base` package. Add if it is not listed in there.

Comment: But why does `Meteor.user()` returns the current user in Chrome's? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: In firefox does the entire app load?

Comment: Try this in console `Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password)`

Comment: Ill try that in a bit. Ill report later. Thanks

Comment: Im already logged in. Strange thing is, when navigate to another page and click back on the profile link, the page loads fine. But once I refreshed, the error returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to this. I hope others find this very useful. Basically I wish to bind the input fields with user's data (profile fields). Upon user registration, I add a profile field and set it to an empty array: `profile: []`

I need not to use `getInitialState()` but instead use `getMeteorData()`. With same code, I need to move the component's render in a function and render that:

```
...

renderedComponent(){
 let instance = this;
 render(<div><input value={instance.data.currentUser.profile.name} /></div>)
},

// we now wait until currentUser is loaded before calling the render function
render(){
 return(<div>{this.data.currentUser? this.renderedComponent() : <p>Loading...</p>}</div>)
}

...
```

To sum up, nothing is wrong with firefox or any part of my code. When working with Meteor and React, this is the best approach.